# How do I print only 3 values per line with right alignment?

Tags: python, format

The below is my current code. However, I want to print only 3 values per line with 5 spaces between column with right alignment. I am trying to get my code to match with the image below.

def formats():

```
import random
lst = [] 
for i in range(100):
    lst.append(random.uniform(0, 1000)) #Get a random number btw 0 and 1000

num = eval(input('Enter number of values to retrieve: '))
for x in range(num+1):
    print('${:>5,.2f}'.format(lst[x]), end='     ')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well, I tried this, and it is working fine,

```py
for x in range(num):
    print('${:>5,.2f}'.format(lst[x]), end='     ')
    if (x+1)%3==0:
        print('\n')
```

I don't know why you were using `range(num+1)`. If you want 19 values, this will be returning 20.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but works fine. Including the justification.

```
import random
lst = [] 
for i in range(100):
    lst.append(random.uniform(0, 1000)) #Get a random number btw 0 and 1000

num = eval(input('Enter number of values to retrieve: '))

groups_of_3 = [lst[0:num][i:i+3] for i in range(0, num, 3)]

for group in groups_of_3:
    for value in group:
        justfied_num = (str(value).split(".")[0] + "." + str(value).split(".")[1][0:2]).rjust(6)
        print(f'${justfied_num}', end='     ')
    print()
```